# Android best way to have a broadcast receiver communicate with a service and an activity communicate with the service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-service

In my android app I have a broadcast receiver that listens for network related intents(android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE). 
Whenever there is a change in the network connection the broadcast receiver receives the intent and it needs to pass on the new connection state to a service. This service keeps track of the connection state of the device. 
Next I have an activity that will have to communicate with the service to find the connection state of the device and do some action based on the connection state. 
What will be the best way to handle the communications with the broadcast receiver with the service and next the activity with the service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this and there is no "best way". It all depends on what other communication is going on between these components.

`Activity` can send data to `Service` using extras in an `Intent` on `startService()`.

`Service` can send data to an `Activity` using extras in an `Intent` on `startActivity()`

`Service` can send data to any component using extras in a broadcast `Intent`. Other components (activities, broadcast receivers, etc.) can register `BroadcastReceiver`s to listen for the data from the `Service`.

`Activity` can also bind to a `Service` which will allow 2 way communication between the `Activity` and `Service` using method calls (AIDL). These method calls can be synchronous or asynchronous.

If the components are all running in the same process, you can store state in `static` variables and share data that way.

You need to look at your whole application and see what data needs to move from component to component and then choose a method that satisfies those requirements.

Comment: Is it considered safe to share data via static variables in case they are in the same process? I mean often it is the way with absolutely less overhead usually always work. Though of course bad for testing etc. I find none of the ways particularly good actually. How about observable pattern btw?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the service is using the same process as the rest of the app if I didn't change it manually?

Comment: @einUsername Yes. If you do not explicitly (in the manifest declaration for the `<service>`) declare that the `Service` should run in another process, it will run in the same process as the other components (`Activity`, `BroadcastReceiver`, `Provider`). The default behaviour is that all components run in a single OS process.